# Build Settings needed to do Casting of (int) --> (UILabel*)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The following "Old" code loaded into XCode 4.2 will work.

But if I start a "new project" and "CUT AND PASTE" the code, I get ERROR: Cast of 'int' to 'UILabel*' is disallowed with ARC

I assume there is a setting in the "Build settings" that I need to set... what do I do?

Thanks...

(and yes I purposely want to do this, too much old code to convert! )

```
int mice[10];

for (int z=0; z<10; z++) {
    UILabel *b = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    mice[z] = (int)b;
}

for (int zz=0; zz<10; zz++) {
    //Old project loaded into XCode 4.2 will work fine with this
    UILabel *c = (UILabel*) mice[zz];// New project: fails <---------- Cast of 'int' to 'UILabel*' is disallowed with ARC


    [self.view addSubview:c]; 
}
```

Comment: During the creation of the new project you would have been given the choice of whether or not to use ARC. Don't. If you already have and you can't start over, the compiler switch is `-fobjc-arc`. I'm not in a position at the moment to check the build setting name, but searching the Xcode GUI for the above should reveal it.

Comment: ARC is 64bit.  If I disable it..  does what I want to do with malloc and casting, will it not work in 64bit?

Comment: On the Mac, ARC requires 64-bit, but it is not required for 64-bit. It is optional. You have an existing code base that's not compatible with it. It will require substantial changes to work with ARC. You should just not use ARC, at least not immediately. You can transition one translation unit at a time at a later date, if you want. It is also true that casting between `int` and pointers is not 64-bit-compatible. An `int` is smaller than a 64-bit pointer. You can use `intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>` if you must do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You avoid doing such casting as it has an undefined behavior. Create an array of `UILabel`s instead.

Comment: how do you do this dynamically: UILabel *mice[10][20];  ??  typically I use malloc.

Comment: Yes - or using NSArray / NSMutableArray

Comment: I want to do it dynamically!  UILabel *mice[10][20]; is hard set, not dynamic.

Comment: so is `int mice[10];`, but as I said, you can use `NSMutableArray` which is dynamic enough

Comment: this was something general.  I want something like but for objects: int **m =(int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);  loop and set columns.  all this to be dynamic because things change in the code.

Comment: you can do the same with `UILabel*`. I don't understand why do you use `int`s in first place.

Comment: this worked with older XCode as well: NSString** array = malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * 10);  Now it fails... Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'void*' to NSString *' is disallowed with ARC.

Comment: Do `NSString** array = (NSString**)malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * 10);`

Comment: NSString** array = (NSString**)malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * 10); this won't work in XCode 4.2 without removing ARC from the new project build settings

Comment: Then go, as I suggested earlier to NSMutableArray, it is dynamic and should be fine with ARC AFAIK, the casting from/to int is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. No offense, but why not a nsmutablearray? At least then the cast to uilabel works since the base object is id.

Not sure you're going to be able to do the with arc on.  Suggest you disable it if you want to continue using this kind of code.